# My screen keeps flickering when running games?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

When I run games not in fullscreen my screen starts flickering and sometimes it's also a little visible on the other screens. But my main screen starts blinking black turning on and off often, about 5-30 secounds there is 10+ or less blinks. 1 blink usually last about 2-5 sec. Even the monitor input controls that are not connected to the PC goes out. It is like the screen crashes and boot's up again.

And no this is not at cable problem becouse I have tried on another computer with the same cable and it works fine.

I have reinstalled the driver for the graphics card and monitor.
I have also read that it may be that it is running Intel Grapichs, but when I run Heaven Benchmark the GPU under Task Manager ramps up to 100%.

Even when looking around a simple 3D wireframe of a box in the veiwport in the program Blender apprently takes 60+ % of the GPU.

So I'm pretty sure it's a driver error but how do I fix it?

Specs:

- CPU: i9 7920x
- GPU: NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 1080 TI
- Monitor: BenQ XL2730z

This does not show up on any recording on the PC, only the monitors.
And look at the framerate, at the end. This GPU should easily pull 100+ fps.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-9qrJuA6dg

This happend after I swapped power supply but its only 10 watts less. So I don't think it is that.
PSU before 860w.
PSU now 850w.

Comment: Have you tried a different monitor as well?

Comment: @user253751 I have 3 monitors and the black flickering only happens on the BenQ. But other things happen like random white lines. Looks like broken LCD only shows up for 1 sec. And keeps happening again and again, only when ingame.